# Sql Server query is not giving proper result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table `SentNewsletters`. This table has following columns.

```
1. ID
2. Surah_no
3. Aayt
4. Sent_date,
5. Sent_By
```

I want to

```
select id
     ,surah_no
     ,aayt
     ,sent_date (MAx)
```

`Sent_by`, `Surah_no` and `Aayt` have multiple records like Id

```
ID  Surah_no  aayt  sent_date                 Sent_By

1   1         1     2013-04-08 19:39:26.127   Test
2   1         1     2013-04-08 20:03:24.920   Test
3   1         1     2013-04-08 19:39:26.127   Test
4   1         1     2013-04-08 20:03:24.920   Test
5   1         1     2013-04-08 20:19:26.033   User3
6   1         1     2013-04-08 20:24:47.890   User3

select Count(*)
     ,surano
     ,Aaytno
     ,MAx(SENT_DATE) 
from sentnewsletters 
group by SuraNo
     ,Aaytno
```

---

I need Id and Sent_By also

```
select Count(*)
     ID
     ,surano
     ,Aaytno
     ,MAx(SENT_DATE) ,
      Sent_by
from sentnewsletters 
group by SuraNo
     ,Aaytno
```

Comment: ...what is it returning?

Comment: You're using `Surah_no`/`surah` and `Aayt`/`Aaytno` alongside each other. I assume these are the same fields? Could you update the code accordingly?

Comment: Are you seeing an error? or just an incorrect (expected) result?

Comment: You can get `sent_by`, but not `ID` since you need to group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use...

```
select Count(*) as Count
     ,surano
     ,Aaytno
     ,MAx(SENT_DATE) as SentDate ,
      Sent_by
from sentnewsletters 
group by SuraNo
     ,Aaytno
     ,Sent_by
```

You can't group on the `ID` since each record is different, you will essentially have the same  result as just querying the table with...

```
select   1 as Count
         ,surano
         ,Aaytno
         ,SENT_DATE,
          Sent_by
    from sentnewsletters
```

The result woudl look like..

```
Count Surah_no  aayt  sent_date                 Sent_By
4      1         1     2013-04-08 20:03:24.920   Test
2      1         1     2013-04-08 20:24:47.890   User3
```